# GROUP BY statement does not work

Tags: sql

Here is my SQL Server query. When I execute this query, `Group by` was giving me a error

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Column 'master_order.order_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

My tables in relation but he did not find why if cannot use group by its work

```
SELECT     
   master_order.order_id, master_order.order_no, article_order.article_name, 
   size.size_name, transaction_order.quantity, transaction_order.unit_name, 
   transaction_order.rate, transaction_order.amount, transaction_order.discount, 
   transaction_order.net_amount, master_order.order_date, buyer.buyer_name, 
   master_order.shipment_date, bank.bank_name, bank.bank_branch, bank.account_title, 
   master_order.confirmation_date, payment.payment_terms, agent.agent_name, 
   agent.company_name, currency.currency_symbol, master_order.half_day, 
   master_order.half_date, master_order.shipped_board_date, master_order.port_category, 
   port_info_setup.port_name, port_info_setup.country_name, master_order.revised, 
   master_order.confirmed, master_order.ex_factory, master_order.comments, 
   master_order.dis_type
FROM 
   master_order 
INNER JOIN
   transaction_order ON master_order.order_id = transaction_order.order_id 
INNER JOIN
   size ON transaction_order.size_id = size.size_id 
INNER JOIN
   article_order ON transaction_order.article_id = article_order.article_id 
INNER JOIN
   buyer ON master_order.buyer_id = buyer.buyer_id 
INNER JOIN
   port_info_setup ON master_order.port_id = port_info_setup.port_id 
INNER JOIN
   payment ON master_order.payment_id = payment.payment_id 
INNER JOIN
   currency ON master_order.currency_id = currency.currency_id 
INNER JOIN
   bank ON master_order.bank_id = bank.bank_id AND buyer.buyer_id = bank.buyer_id 
INNER JOIN
   agent ON master_order.agent_id = agent.agent_id
GROUP BY 
   size.size_name
```

Comment: This is an incredibly common error, and is fundamental to what `GROUP BY` means: `GROUP BY size.size_name` means "output only one row for each distinct value of `size.size_name`. How should the database choose, for all those other columns you want to select, which value to output in each row?

Comment: if one order have many sizes and some size will same so same size will be combine and show

Comment: Quick example: master_order 1 has sizes S and L; master_order 2 has sizes S, M, and L; master_order 3 has sizes M and L. `GROUP BY size` means we have one row for S, one row for M, and one row for L; in the row for S what value should master_order have, 1 or 2? The database has no way of choosing, so it tells you that your query cannot be answered.

Comment: master_order 1 have 2 size L,M but L have 10 Articles all articles save in individual row if 10 article so means size also written 10 times and save

Comment: But `GROUP BY size` specifically means that you only want one row for size L in the output. If you want more than one row for each size, you don't want `GROUP BY size`. You might want `ORDER BY size`, or you might want to `GROUP BY` multiple columns, or you might want something else entirely.

Comment: I know its means one row but one row is not coming I want one row if articles 10 and size same so come only one row with the group by size

Comment: But what would the values in that row be? How do 10 articles of the same size fit into one row? Note that even if there was no data in the database, the SQL would still be invalid, because it would make no sense to have a query that was sometimes valid and sometimes not based only on the data it could retrieve.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40483/discussion-between-user2491383-and-imsop)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have time for that right now. You can probably find lots of articles about this online, as it really is a very common confusion (although once you understand it, it's a very simple principle).

Comment: Since you don't seem to be understanding @IMSop's repeated attempts at explanation - can you edit your question and add some sample data and expected outputs - and maybe we can help write the query for you. As it is, it's not at all clear what you were expecting this query to do.

Answer (score 0):

In the grouped query ether your columns in the select list should be inside an aggregate function or the column without aggregate should mention in the group by statement.
If you want a column with no aggregate and dont want grouping by that column, so use CTE for grouping and use join to have that column in your query results.